# BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in Devise::SessionsController#createの意味

Tags: ruby-on-rails

BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in Devise::SessionsController#createとエラーが表示されました。 
またinvalid hashとも表示されました。これは、SessionsControllerのcreateアクションのhashが無効である、という意味かなと思いましたが、SessionsControllerなるものをつくっていないです。解釈が間違っているのでしょうか？

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller? 
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception. 
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead. 
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # privateメソッドを定義し、deviseの新規登録フォームでnameを受け取れるようにしてください 
  include ApplicationHelper

  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters 
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:name,:email,:username,:password] 
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << [:login,:username,:remember_me] 
  end 
end
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController 
  def top 
      if user_signed_in? 
      # 変数@noteにNoteクラスのインスタンスを代入してください 
      @note = Note.new 
      # 変数@notesにNoteクラスのインスタンスの配列を降順で代入してください 
      @notes = Note.all.order(created_at: :desc) 
    else 
      @message = "ようこそKotoritterへ！" 
    end 
  end

  def about 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Devise::SessionsController`はDeviseで実際に認証などの処理をしているControllerです。

Deviseを使ってユーザー認証をする場合、ユーザー登録時、パスワードは元の文字列そのままではなく、元の文字列に戻せないよう変換した形でDBに保存されます。この処理をやっているのがBCryptというライブラリです。

この変換処理を施した後の文字列は、`$2a$05$CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.E5YPO9kmyuRGyh0XouQYb4YMJKvyOeW`こんな感じになっているのですが、一定の書式がある文字列になっています。

`BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash`は、BCryptが上記の文字列を読み込んだ時に適切なフォーマットになっていないと発生する例外です。

DBの`users`テーブル(Deviseのセットアップ時に変更した場合は適宜読み替えてください)の`ecrypted_password`に保存されている値が不正な値になっていると思います。